# Devise-JWT: Unable to access Authorization header when making AJAX requests to `/users/sign_in`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have a react frontend that is sending AJAX requests to `/users/sign_in`, except the react frontend can't access any of the Authorization headers that should be coming back.

I suspect it's because the rails backend is sending a 302 redirect on successful login.

I need access to the Authorization headers, and it seems that the frontend has no choice but to follow redirects.

Do I need to stop devise from redirecting on successful login, or is there some other reason my frontend is unable to see the Authorization headers?

I've installed a gem called `devise-jwt` which adds an Authorization header to the response on successful login attempts.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add the below code in your application.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource(
      '*',
      headers: :any,
      expose: ["Authorization"],
      methods: [:get, :patch, :put, :delete, :post, :options,               :show]
    )
  end
```

end

Comment: Yeah I've added that and I'm still not seeing it. I think I need to turn off redirection after successful login attempts.

If I use cURL and make a bare no-follow POST request to `/users/sign_in`, the response is a 302 with an Authorization header included.

So I can see the result just fine with cURL... it's this damn 302 redirect that the browser (from what I've read) must follow... and so it looks like the headers are just lost.